# Toggle pop up on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to toggle an menu on a mouseclick. Usually i did this with an image and href but on this project i took an existing button from the web and i cant figure it out working.

Here's my code:

```js
let menuOpen = false;
menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(!menuOpen) {
    menuBtn.classList.add('open');
    menuOpen = true;
  } else {
    menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
    menuOpen = false;
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav1").on("click", function() {
      $("popup").toggleClass("open");
    });
  });
```

```css
.menu-btn {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    /* border: 3px solid #fff; */
  }
  .menu-btn__burger {
    width: 50px;
    height: 6px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(255,101,47,.2);
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  }
  .menu-btn__burger::before,
  .menu-btn__burger::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 6px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(255,101,47,.2);
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  }
  .menu-btn__burger::before {
    transform: translateY(-16px);
  }
  .menu-btn__burger::after {
    transform: translateY(16px);
  }
  /* ANIMATION */
  .menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger {
    transform: translateX(-50px);
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger::before {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(35px, -35px);
  }
  .menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger::after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(35px, 35px);
  }

  #popup {
      position: fixed;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: white;
      display:none;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: 0.5s;
  }

  #popup.open {
      display: block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup">
            <nav id="main-nav">
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Über uns</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Galerie</a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
        </div>
```

I am absolutely clueless.
I want to achieve that when the Button is clicked, the popup window opens and when i click it again that i closes.

Comment: Please share more `js` and `html` and use snippet to make the problem clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put `#` before popup since it is id.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#nav1").on("click", function() {
    $("#popup").toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

Comment: Yea you are right. But sadly it still doesnt work...

Comment: can you put some more HTML and javascript code in the question?